# Why is Recordset.AddNew updating the database without .Update executing?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I've written a function in Excel to upload a record to an Access database. I was simulating an Error after executing recordset.AddNew and before rs.Update. I would expect the database not to  save the record unless .Update executes however, the record is saved. My understanding is that the record should not be committed to the database until rs.Update executes. What's happening here?

Here's some VBA code from my module to help recreate the error (you'll also need to set up an Access DB called 'EAS' with a Table called 'Statements' and a field called 'GroupID':

###### Module Variables

```
'Connection
Const PWORD As String = "password"
Dim sSQL As String 'SQL string
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection 'ADODB Connection object
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset 'ADODB Recordset object

'Paths
Const EAS_DB As String = "J:\yourpath\EAS.accdb"
```

###### Open Database Connection

```
Private Sub openConnect()
'opens the DB connection, let errors occur

Dim cnnString As String
    cnnString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & EAS_DB & ";" & _
                "Jet OLEDB:Database Password='" & PWORD & "';"
    cnn.Open cnnString
End Sub
```

###### Close Database Connection

```
Private Sub closeConnect()
'closes recordset and connection cleanly, handle errors


Dim rsFail As Boolean
    rsFail = True

On Error GoTo eh:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then
        If rs.State = adStateOpen Then
            rs.Close
            Set rs = Nothing
        End If
    End If      

closeCnn:
    rsFail = False
    If Not cnn Is Nothing Then
        If cnn.State = adStateOpen Then
            cnn.Close
            Set cnn = Nothing
        End If
    End If
Exit Sub
   
eh:
    If rsFail Then
        GoTo closeCnn:
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Source & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description, , "Error in closeConnect"
    End If
End Sub
```

###### The function which records to the database

```
Private Function createPendingRecord(ByVal idarray As Variant, ByVal amount As Double) As Boolean
'Attempts to create a new pending record in the database, returns boolean result

Dim data As Variant
Dim flds As Variant  

'Get data and field arrays for upload
data(0) = "12345"
flds(0) = "GroupID"

On Error GoTo eh:
  
    openConnect
    rs.Open "Statements", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    rs.AddNew flds, data
    Error 0
    rs.Update
    createPendingRecord = True

cleanExit:
    closeConnect
    Exit Function

eh:
    MsgBox Err.Source & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description, , "Error in createPendingRecord"
    Resume cleanExit
   
End Function
```

As you can see, I have inserted the line `Error 0` between `rs.AddNew` and `rs.Update`. This then triggers the error handler and the code gracefully exits using `closeConnect`, **without** `rs.Update` executing. However, the record is present in the database afterwards.

My understanding is that it shouldn't be. Confused. Please can someone explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your understanding is mistaken. This is the intended behavior.

Looking at the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/addnew-method-ado?view=sql-server-ver16):

> The behavior of the AddNew method depends on the updating mode of the
> Recordset object and whether you pass the Fieldlist and Values
> arguments.
>
> In immediate update mode (in which the provider writes changes to the
> underlying data source once you call the Update method), calling the
> AddNew method without arguments sets the EditMode property to
> adEditAdd (an EditModeEnum value). The provider caches any field value
> changes locally. Calling the Update method posts the new record to the
> database and resets the EditMode property to adEditNone (an
> EditModeEnum value). If you pass the Fieldlist and Values arguments,
> ADO immediately posts the new record to the database (no Update call
> is necessary); the EditMode property value does not change
> (adEditNone).

Since you're passing the field and value list, and are not using batch mode, the new record is written immediately and the subsequent `.Update` is unneccesary.

If you want to cancel actions, the most straightforward ways is to use transactions (see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/begintrans-committrans-and-rollbacktrans-methods-example-vb?view=sql-server-ver16)), that will allow you much greater control over when changes are written to the database.

Or, you could assign fields and values one by one and not use the field and value list in `.AddNew`, which would work for this specific action.

Comment: I looked at the doc before posting the question but read the DAO doc not ADO - my bad! Thanks for the clarification. I'm using the field and values lists because in the actual code I'm passing multiple values, not just one, and this feels the cleaner way to do it.  I tend only to use transactions when assigning to more than one table, to maintain referential integrity. This is just assigning to a single table.